# Кто автор стихотворения?

Tags: литература

Есть довольно известное стихотворение:
*"В одно окно смотрели двое...

Один увидел — дождь и грязь,

Другой — листвы зеленой вязь,

Весну и небо голубое...

В одно окно смотрели двое..."*

На одном сайте было написано, что автор - Омар Хайям. Но это совершенно не его стиль, поэтому я засомневалась и стала искать автора. В другом месте было написано, что автор - якобы - Расул Гамзатов. В третьем - что это Расул Гамзатов переделал Омара Хайяма.
Может быть, кто-то знает точно автора?

Comment: По стилю очень похоже на Эдуарда Асадова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не Омар Хайям. Правда, на эту тему у него есть похожее:

Один не разберет, чем пахнут розы…

Другой из горьких трав добудет мед…

Кому-то мелочь дашь, навек запомнит…

Кому-то жизнь отдашь, а он и не поймет…

И не Расул Гамзатов. Это вообще не поэт. Практический психолог Н. Козлов написал книгу по семейной психологии и поместил там это четверостишие без ссылок на чьё-то авторство (хотя на другие строки ссылки есть), значит, сам и сочинил. Вот ссылка на электронный вариант, там на стр. 150 найдёте стихотворение.

http://nkozlov.ru/s_att.php?aid=33

Кто-то, видимо, читал, понравилось - поместил себе в блог - и пошло гулять по Интернету с продолжением в разных вариациях.

В одно окно смотрели двое.

Один увидел дождь и грязь,

Другой - "лежит печёный язь",

Вокруг застолье удалое,

И рыбаки пьют, веселясь.

Вот так сквозь стёкла смотрим мы,

Вся разница - с какой ты стороны.

=====================================

В одно окно смотрели двое,

И каждый видел что-нибудь,

Хотя постой, не в окнах суть!

Есть взгляды с видами на море,

А есть - на луж прогоркших муть!

Answer (score 5):

> *Практический психолог Н.Козлов написал книгу по семейной психологии и
> поместил там это четверостишие без
> ссылок на чьё-то авторство(хотя на
> другие строки ссылки есть), **ЗНАЧИТ**,
> сам и сочинил.*

Здесь -- http://citaty.info/quote/192652 -- более корректно:

По поводу авторства Николая Козлова: В его книге «Как относиться к себе и людям...» я нашла именно первый стих и при этом в книге не написано, что это цитата, т. е. ***СКОРЕЕ ВСЕГО*** он и написал этот стих к своей книге. (Эл. книга — http://nkozlov.ru/s_att.php?aid=33 , стр. 150).

Comment: Хм... И почему же за такой ответ нужно ставить "минусы"?

Comment: Не обращайте внимания. Ответ вполне заслуживает уважения.